# Pug, splitting into different includes

Tags: html, pug

I wonder if it's possible to create an include in Pug where the include file partially is a bit of a div?

I am importing the include with: `include includes/footer`

So in the example below, I don't want to close the ul.boxes in the parent file, but in the include file.

For example in the main file, I have the following structure:

```
ul.boxes
    li
    li
    li
```

and then in the include I want to continue the li structure with just the li:s, but I want to close the parent ul.boxes in the include.

Is this possible at all with Pug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I just tested this and it generated the list as expected:

```
ul
  include ./include_a1
  include ./include_a2
  include ./include_a3
```

The include files each contain one line:

```
li Item A.1
```

This was the generated HTML:

```
<ul><li>Item A.1</li><li>Item A.2</li><li>Item A.3</li></ul>
```

You can also easily do this with a [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html).

In a separate file your mixin can live by itself:

```
mixin listItem(value)
  li= value
```

Then your main pug file will look like this:

```
include file_with_mixin

ul
  +listItem('Item A.1')
  +listItem('Item A.2')
  +listItem('Item A.3')
```

This will produce the exact same output as the straight include method above, but have the benefit of controlling all formatting in the common mixin file and driving presentation logic independently of the data.

That matters if you wanted to bold all of the `li` elements you would do it in the mixin file only and not need to edit three separate include files.

Comment: good Thanks, now it works out, I think i probably did not indent the code in a proper hierarchy before :) The mixin is really a good idea :) 

But is it possible to have a mixin or include with two different sets of code, I have two different types of footer code, and I would like to import the right footer code, do I need two different include files, or can I somehow select the proper block of code from the same include file with some sort of if statement?

Comment: I think that needs to be a separate question :)